# Boostrap 4 dynamically place card (info fetched from DB)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a CMS (content managment system).

I am stuck on the part where I am fetching DB information to a page where info is placed in Bootstrap 4 card class. The problem is that when I remove one card the last card position is not moving one up.

Basically, the html code is

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 2)
        {
            if (Model[i].DisplayStatus == true)
            {
                <div class="card card-body text-center">
                    <div class="card-title">
                        <h2 class="font-weight-bold">@Model[i].Autors</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-text">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(Model[i].ImagePath)" class="img-fluid" /><br /><br />
                        <h4>@Model[i].Teksts</h4>
                    </div>
                    <a href="/Home/MoreInfo?id=@Model[i].ID" class="btn btn-info">More info <i class="fa fa-info"></i></a>
                </div><br />
            }
        }
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        @for (int i = 1; i < Model.Count(); i += 2)
        {
            if (Model[i].DisplayStatus == true)
            {
                <div class="card card-body text-center">
                    <div class="card-title">
                        <h2 class="font-weight-bold">@Model[i].Autors</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-text">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(Model[i].ImagePath)" class="img-fluid" /><br /><br />
                        <h4>@Model[i].Teksts</h4>
                    </div>
                    <a href="/Home/MoreInfo?id=@Model[i].ID" class="btn btn-info">More info <i class="fa fa-info"></i></a>
                </div><br />
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is that these cards will align dynamically. If one place is empty (`DisplayStatus == false`) the next card takes it place and so on. Basically a dynamic card alignment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your end html after a card is removed. It is impossible to tell that much from your current code as this is the setup and not the tear down.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put  inside the if statement

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#column-wrapping

```
<div class="row">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i ++)
        {
            if (Model[i].DisplayStatus == true)
            {
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card card-body text-center">
                    <div class="card-title">
                        <h2 class="font-weight-bold">@Model[i].Autors</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-text">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(Model[i].ImagePath)" class="img-fluid" /><br /><br />
                        <h4>@Model[i].Teksts</h4>
                    </div>
                    <a href="/Home/MoreInfo?id=@Model[i].ID" class="btn btn-info">More info <i class="fa fa-info"></i></a>
                </div><br />
            </div>
            }
        }
</div>
```